# WPF Autocomplete Combobox Not Saving To Database VB

Tags: wpf

Trying to create what i feel should be an easy WPF application. basically what i want it to do is have a autocomplete combobox which is bound to a sql db table. the table has 2 fields(Address and Directions)

once the user selects the record from the address combox the directions textbox below will be filled directions stored in the table.

if there are no records in the address combobox the user can then type in the combobox and add the new entry.

there will be a save button on the form that saves the new entry and will be visible in the list. Im new to WPF applications and have been trying to get this to work for weeks. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking out the following discussion which will point you to several good tutorials on using the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern with WPF.

[MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

Other than that, you haven't really given any indication what you've tried and what isn't working so I can't really offer any other advice. But even the simplest applications in WPF are much cleaner and more easily implemented with MVVM than using code behind and drag and drop data binding.